# location of the local repository that apache zeppelin check changes into

Tags: git, apache-zeppelin

I have followed the link https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.6.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT/storage/storage.html#Git to check in any changes done on zeppelin into git.

But I have this doubt.
 - How do I indicate the location of the local repository on which zeppelin will have to check its changes into?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ooh after looking at the logs of zeppelin carefully, I was able to find the location of the local repository. That is 
/home/user/zeppelin-0.5.6-incubating-bin-all/notebook/.

Hope this helps someone in the future.